# How to get the maximum value of the whole dataframe in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, max

I already sorted the data and the dataframe now is like this:

```
              Tr Srate(V/ns)mean  Tf Srate(V/ns)mean
CPULabel                                            
100HiBW_Fast                3.16                3.09
100LoBW_Fast                3.16                3.09
BP100_Fast                  3.16                3.06
```

My dataframe is slew_rate_max. I tried to use:

```
slew_rate_max.max()
```

I expected the result to be 3.16. However, I got the max values of both columns individually.

```
Tr Srate(V/ns)mean    3.16
Tf Srate(V/ns)mean    3.09
dtype: float64
```

How to get the max value of the whole dataframe not of each column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
slew_rate_max.max().max()
```

`slew_rate_max.max()` returns a series with the max of each column, then taking the `max` again of that series will give you the max of the entire dataframe.

or

```
slew_rate_max.values.max()
```

`slew_rate_max.values` converts the dataframe to a np.ndarray then using [numpy.ndarray.max](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html#numpy.ndarray.max) which as an argument `axis` that the default is `None`, this gives the max of the entire ndarray.

Comment: which one would be faster among these options? doesn't it even matter when there are a million rows?

Comment: @Freak I am pretty sure that `slew_rate_max.to_numpy().max()` is faster.